# Repeat Value for Every Instance of Another Value in Excel without using Power Query

Tags: excel, join, powerquery

I have about a thousand products in a table. In another table, I have 33 price contracts. I need an instance of each product for every contract.

For example, if I had the 4 following products:

| product |
| --- |
| ProductA |
| ProductB |
| ProductC |
| ProductD |

and the four following contracts:

| contract |
| --- |
| contract1 |
| contract2 |
| contract3 |
| contract4 |

I could load the following table in to Power Query

| product | contract1 | contract2 | contract3 | contract4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| productA | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| productB | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| productC | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| productD | 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

and after unpivoting the contract columns get this

| product | attribute |
| --- | --- |
| productA | contract1 |
| productA | contract2 |
| productA | contract3 |
| productA | contract4 |
| productB | contract1 |
| productB | contract2 |
| productB | contract3 |
| productB | contract4 |
| productC | contract1 |
| productC | contract2 |
| productC | contract3 |
| productC | contract4 |
| productD | contract1 |
| productD | contract2 |
| productD | contract3 |
| productD | contract4 |

This seems like an inefficient and roundabout way of getting the last table. Is there a more efficient way of doing this in excel?

Answer (score 2):

You initally said you dont want powerquery for some reason,  but it can be done much simpler then your example. Load the first table. Load the second table, and in that query, add column, custom column, with formula **=OtherTableName**.  Expand the new column into rows using arrows at top the column.  Here. we start with Table2 and use =Table1 then expand

[image]

```
let  Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Custom", each Table1),
#"Expanded Custom" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Added Custom", "Custom", {"Column1"}, {"Table1"})
in  #"Expanded Custom"
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's another couple of dynamic array options for `MS365`...

**(1) To include a single column from each table:**

```
=LET(
    array1, Table1[product],
    array2, Table2[contract],
    HSTACK(
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(, ROWS(array2)), array1)),
        TOCOL(IF(SEQUENCE(, ROWS(array1)), array2),, TRUE)
    )
)
```

**(2) To include ALL columns from both tables:**

```
=LET(
    a, SEQUENCE(ROWS(Table1)),
    b, SEQUENCE(, ROWS(Table2)),
    HSTACK(
        CHOOSEROWS(Table1, TOCOL(IF(b, a))),
        CHOOSEROWS(Table2, TOCOL(IF(a, b)))
    )
)
```

[image: merge_tables2.png]

Answer (score 1):

If using `MS365` then could try one of the following formulas as well:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>F2</kbd>

```
=LET(
     _Merged, TOCOL(B3:B6&"|"&TOROW(D3:D6)),
     TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&_Merged,"|",{1,2}),"|"))
```

---

Or, another way:

```
=LET(
     _Merged, TOCOL(B3:B6&"|"&TOROW(D3:D6)),
     HSTACK(TEXTBEFORE(_Merged,"|"),TEXTAFTER(_Merged,"|")))
```

---