How to get the cartesian product (cross join) of two sets via Excel Formulas
I need to get the cartesian product of two "sets" via Excel 365 Formulas (not VBA, not Power Query). For instance, my two sets are the two left tables, and the expected cartesian product is the right table:
Cartesian product of two sets in Excel 365

How to get the cartesian product with one Excel formula?
If possible, I'd like a general answer, to work for any two sets, whatever values they contain, whatever the number of columns is in the two sets.
The two sets:



Column1
Column2

Column1
Column2




4500005010
A

PO start
D


4500005011
B

header merge
E


4500005012
C

PO activate
F




This doesn't require a LAMBDA() helper: =TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&TOCOL(DataOne[Column1]&"|"&DataOne[Column2]&"|"&TOROW(DataTwo[Column1]&"|"&DataTwo[Column2])),"|",{1,2,3,4}),"|")

Without using LAMBDA() helper function:


=LET(
     a, TOROW(DataTwo[Column1]&"|"&DataTwo[Column2]),
     b, TOCOL(DataOne[Column1]&"|"&DataOne[Column2]&"|"&a),
     TEXTSPLIT(TEXTAFTER("|"&b,"|",SEQUENCE(,4)),"|"))


• Or, Option Two:
=LET(
     a, ROWS(DataTwo),
     b, ROWS(DataOne),
     c, CHOOSEROWS(DataOne,INT((SEQUENCE(a*b)-1)/a)+1),
     d, CHOOSEROWS(DataTwo,MOD((SEQUENCE(a*b)-1),a)+1),
     HSTACK(c,d))


Change variables at the end to evaluate:
=LET(
     a, ROWS(DataTwo),
     b, ROWS(DataOne),
     c, SEQUENCE(a*b),
     d, CHOOSEROWS(DataOne,INT((c-1)/a)+1),
     e, CHOOSEROWS(DataTwo,MOD((c-1),a)+1),
     f, HSTACK(d,e),
     f)



Interesting, thanks. To be honest, I should have added in my question that I wanted to make my question general, to work for any two sets, whatever value they contain (e.g. pipe in text), whatever the number of columns is in the two sets. Let me rephrase a little bit.

@SandraRossi see the Option 2

Just a last question, is there any reason to have f, why not indicating directly HSTACK(d,e)?

@SandraRossi yes you can directly have the HSTACK() I kept the f for you to evaluate. Helps to play around the variables to understand easily and debug. While you can avoid the same as well! No hard rules there you can avoid it and write directly HSTACK(d,e)

A generalized option could be:
=CROSSJOIN(Table1,Table2)

Where CROSSJOIN is a custom function defined in Name Manager:
=LAMBDA(array1,array2,
    LET(
        i, SEQUENCE(ROWS(array1)),
        j, SEQUENCE(, ROWS(array2)),
        HSTACK(
            CHOOSEROWS(array1, TOCOL(IF(j, i))),
            CHOOSEROWS(array2, TOCOL(IF(i, j)))
        )
    )
)

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78244826/22459970
If you also wanted the option to handle header rows, CROSSJOIN can be defined as follows:
=LAMBDA(array1,array2,[headers],
    LET(
        incl_h, CHOOSE(headers + 1, 0, 1, 0, 1),
        show_h, CHOOSE(headers + 1, 0, 0, 1, 1),
        a, DROP(array1, incl_h),
        b, DROP(array2, incl_h),
        i, SEQUENCE(ROWS(a)),
        j, SEQUENCE(, ROWS(b)),
        v, HSTACK(
            CHOOSEROWS(a, TOCOL(IF(j, i))),
            CHOOSEROWS(b, TOCOL(IF(i, j)))
        ),
        IF(
            show_h,
            VSTACK(
                IF(
                    incl_h,
                    HSTACK(
                        TAKE(array1, 1),
                        TAKE(array2, 1)
                    ),
                    HSTACK(
                        "tbl1.Col" & SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(a)),
                        "tbl2.Col" & SEQUENCE(, COLUMNS(b))
                    )
                ),
                v
            ),
            v
        )
    )
)

The optional [headers] argument will behave in a similar fashion to that of the [field_headers] argument of GROUPBY, where the following options are accepted:

0 | No
1 | Yes but don't show
2 | No but generate
3 | Yes and show

For example:
=CROSSJOIN(Table1,Table2,2)

Or:
=CROSSJOIN(Table1[#All],Table2[#All],3)

Please note, the line breaks and spaces/indentations were used for improved readability. They can be removed when defining the function in Name Manager.

Thanks for the solution; nice idea to keep the headers; thanks also for the link to the other question that I couldn't find before posting (NB: I have added [tag:cartesian-product] and [tag:cross-join] to the other question). NB: for information, GROUPBY is currently available only to Excel 365 Insiders.

There's a solution based on MAKEARRAY:

=MAKEARRAY(
  ROWS(Set_1)*ROWS(Set_2),
  COLUMNS(Set_1)+COLUMNS(Set_2),
  LAMBDA(row,col,
         LET(set_num,IF(col<=COLUMNS(Set_1),1,2),CHOOSE(set_num,
            INDEX(Set_1,QUOTIENT(row-1,3)+1,col),
            INDEX(Set_2,MOD(row-1,3)+1,col-COLUMNS(Set_1))))))


Cartesian Product
=LET(data1,Table11,data2,Table12,
    Repeat,LAMBDA(fs,ss,by_col,
        TOCOL(IF(TOROW(ss),fs),,by_col)),
    fs,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data1)),
    ss,SEQUENCE(ROWS(data2)),
    HSTACK(CHOOSEROWS(data1,Repeat(fs,ss,0)),
        CHOOSEROWS(data2,Repeat(ss,fs,1))))


TOCOL/IF/SEQUENCE
Efficiency

Not once have I encountered this combo being more efficient than the INT/MOD combo. Not when using them as they are (no visible difference) but when combined with other functions.
In this particular case, on two tables of 1000 rows by 5 columns, this combo took 10s while the INT/MOD solution by Mayukh Bhattacharya (the nice one with c, SEQUENCE(a*b),) took 14s. Your MAKEARRAY solution took 23s.


IF/SEQUENCE

To get more familiar with this combination, feel free to download Repeat Column from my OneDrive.


Thanks for this importance aspect of performance. These Microsoft VBA macros can help: Measuring calculation time.
